# How to make Rails submit a URL to the web for testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I'm writing a piece of test code for my Rails 4 app, and I was wondering if there's a way to automate it in order to submit a URL to the web every time its run.

Typing a specific URL (http://website.com/add?application=Test&...&severity=ERROR) into a browser search bar populates my database with certain data, and I want to test if changing the parameters of the URL yields the correct results. Is there a way to make my test code do this by itself?

Comment: This seems strange. Why do you populate the database with a GET request?

Comment: I admit that it is a little strange. The honest answer is I'm not sure; I'm a newly-hired intern put in charge of upgrading this application to a newer Rails version. My mentor simply told me to paste in that URL to Safari and check if a new alert notification was correctly added to the database. Now I'm to automate the testing process but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 gems:

1. [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) for generating random stuffs like email addresses, names, phone numbers, etc.
2. [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails), a test automation tool for Ruby on Rails.

There will be some configuration to enable these things. Since you are an intern, I give you a minimum sample.

*In the following steps, the path `/` refers to the root of your rails application, not the root of the file system.*

### Step 1: install these gems

In the `/Gemfile`, add these lines:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'faker'
end
```

Then run `bundle install`.

After the gems are installed, run `rails generate rspec:install`, which generates the folder `/spec/` and some files in it.

### Step 2: write tests

Finally you can write tests.

Run `rails generate rspec:request add`, it will give you a test script file at `/spec/requests/adds_spec.rb`. It looks like

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Adds", type: :request do

  describe "GET /adds" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
      get adds_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
end
```

Now modify it

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Add", type: :request do

  let(:application) {Faker::Lorem.word}
  let(:severity) {%w(trace debug info error fatal).sample}
  # other params ...

  describe "GET /add" do
    it "creates some record" do
      get add_path(application: application, severity: severity)
      my_model = MyModel.last!
      expect(my_model.application).to == application
      # other expectations ...
    end
  end
end
```

Then run it with `bundle exec rspec spec`.

P.S. You may need [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) to clean up database after each test. You may also need [factory_girl_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) to help you create fixtures. You may need [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) to mimic human using browsers. You may ... So find yourself a textbook about Rails.